# Finishing A Newly Installed Stair Landing

Tags: basement, stairs, finishing, landing

I am currently wrapping up finishing my basement, and am trying to figure out what to do with my stair landing. Because of a ~2" increase in height compared to my old basement floor, I had to install a 36" long landing to compensate. Currently the landing just has the unfinished OSB, but I want to finish it off with hardwood or something (the basement floor is a hickory floating engineered hardwood).

My question is, how can I finish this 36" landing to cover up the ugly OSB? I see I can purchase stair noses which is fine, but for landing treads I don't see anything that can cover my 36". I'm assuming my floating floor would not work on this landing?

Thanks in advanced

EDIT: Added pictures for clarity

[image: Top View]

[image: Bottom View]

Comment: A couple pictures will help us visualize what you are working with

Comment: Sure thing, added to the main post. Thanks for looking!

Comment: The floating floor should work if it is well supported(like a floor) and has a stop at the end to keep it from sliding off.  The last step and OSB does not seem to be flat and level enough, looks like a ridge there.

Comment: There is a bit of a ridge there, I'll check when I can how flat it is. If its not flat enough, are there any other suggestions for how to cover this up? Even if its not a 100% color match to my floor that would be fine.